# Making Bootstrap Card relatively small in all perspective

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**My Requirement**

1. I need to make a bootstrap card that is small in size so that it fits my page exactly.
2. need to remove much of the padding, margin spaces around the card, text, icon ...
   That is, it should be as small as possible to fit 8 (equal-sized) such cards in a row
   so that all the parameters exactly fit in a single page view along with 2 charts displayed above as shown in the below screenshot.
   [image: dashboard]

The code below in Bootstrap gets me the card as shown in this image. I am trying to make the same card, kind of replica of the card but small in size.

[image: bootstrap_card]

```
<div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class=" card card-stats">
        <div class=" card-body">
          <div class=" row">
            <div class=" col-5">
              <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
                <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-7">
              <div class=" numbers">
                <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
                <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" card-footer">
          <hr />

          <div class=" stats">
            <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**What I have tried**
I tried to change the bootstrap's CSS element  `col` number (col-1,col-5..), remove padding for  the CSS element `card,card-body,  ... , info-icon` to make the icon relatively small
But it doesn't get me its replica w.r.t the text, icon.
It always ended up with a messed up card.

Please help me. *My ultimate goal* is to make it smaller and include additional data (4 parameter data) within the card which should look something like this
[image: required_bootstrap_card]

That is

1. an icon at the top left corner

   2. First Data at the top right corner
   3. Second Data above the footer of the card below icon
   4. Third Data right side corner, right-aligned to second data #3 mentioned above
   5. Fourth Data in the Footer.

Also if you have any other good ideas to include 4 parameter data in a single card please share it with me.
This I do to fit all parameters within the single page view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `col` class instead of `col-lg-3 col-md-6`. so, you can set 8 columns in one row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class=" card card-stats">
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class=" row">
          <div class=" col-5">
            <div class=" info-icon text-center icon-primary">
              <i class=" icons icon-shape-star"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col-7">
            <div class=" numbers">
              <p class=" card-category">Followers</p>
              <h3 class=" card-title">+45k</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" card-footer">
        <hr />

        <div class=" stats">
          <i class=" icons icon-sound-wave"> </i> Last Research
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow works like a charm. Thanks @Nisharg Shah. If possible can you also help me place the 4 parameters inside the card; For me if I add something there, something goes off :-( - messy.

Comment: what, I dont understand, what 4 params?

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote thanks!!

Comment: I want to add 4 data values inside the card (say value for  Average, Min,Max,Range)

Comment: Yes I've added the image. Its the second image. It's below `my Ultimate Goal` Thanks for the help.